# URL rewriting in PHP Codeigniter.

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am new to PHP and this piece of code is passed on to me, that is its not written by me. Link are defined like this in the code:

`<a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>/schools/showschool/<?php echo $key;?>/"`

So if I click on icon **Show School** it gives me `http://localhost/schools/showschool/21323/` rather than `http://localhost/admin.schools/schools/showschool/21323/`

if I manually add `admin.schools` or write the code as

`<a href="<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>admin.schools/schools/showschool/<?php echo $key;?>/"`

the URL it opens up fine.

I am assuming that `<?php echo ADMIN_URL;?>` where `ADMIN_URL` is defined somewhere plays a part. I cannot find it in config.php, route.php or .htaccess files.

Am I looking in the wrong files? If not, and it is missing then how and where do I define `ADMIN_URL` ?

Comment: search for the statement `define('ADMIN_URL'`

Answer (score 1):

Open your SSH Terminal (like putty.exe) and run the following command

```
grep -R ADMIN_URL /var/www/html
```

Where `/var/www/html` needs to be your server root folder.
The Terminal will then print the location in where the ADMIN_URL is defined and you can change it from there usually it is defined in the constants.php

Change the statment to:

```
define('ADMIN_URL', '/admin.schools/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead of `ADMIN_URl`.

You can also use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter use base_url() to get root path